# How can I figure out why an HID unikey device is not being recognized by the software needing it?

Tags: centos, usb, virtualbox, hid

I have a custom built CentOS machine. For those of you who know [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com), the image is at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puppetlabs/boxes/centos-7.2-64-puppet.

When I connect an HID Unikey device to this virtual machine, I get a text in `journalctl -f` saying that the USB device was attached. However, the software supposed to work with this device does not recognize it.

How can I debug this? The machine image is about 200-300 MB, and I'm guessing maybe I need an extra package so that the software will have access to USB locks.

Comment: What device, what software should use it? Does it work on a bare machine?

Comment: It is a UniKey, one of those USB devices that are meant to act as a hardware lock. The software will not work without the USB key not plugged in. I have tested the device on a real machine, VMWare machine and a machine with VirtualBox. It works in the first two instances.